# For syntax error

Tags: python

Начинаю изучать питон:
В чем я ошибся.

```
a = 2
b = 10
c = 3
d = 9
for(int i<=b; i=a; i++):
    if i<=d and i>=c:
        s=i*i
        print(s)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: `В чем я ошибся` - в том что python это не C/C++/C#/Java и т.д., синтаксис for в нем другой (и даже для  перечисленных языков for неправильно записан).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, for в питоне так не пишется.

Ваш код должен выглядит вот так:

```py
a = 2
b = 10
c = 3
d = 9
for i in range(d):
    if i<=d and i>=c:
        s=i*i
        print(s)
    else:
        print(i)
```

И вот почитайте: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/cikl-for-in

Comment: В вопросе вроде как пытались проитерироваться по `range(a, b+1)`...

Comment: @GrAnd, взгляните на эту строчку